# Netbean SQL check if name exists in database

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am trying to check, if a specific value already exists in my database. Can anyone tell me, whats wrong with my statements? And also I can't insert data into MySQL. Thanks

```
try {                      
               Statement s = c.createStatement();
             final String queryCheck = "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM pengguna WHERE pengguna.username = '"+ username +"'";
final PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
ps.setString(1, username);
final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
if(resultSet.next()) {
  final int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
}
else{
                this.sql = "INSERT INTO pengguna (password, username, nama, umur, agama, pekerjaan, alamat) "
                        + "VALUES ('"+ password +"', '"+ username +"', '"+ nama +"', '"+ umur +"', '"+ agama +"', '"+ pekerjaan +"', '"+ alamat +"')";             
                 s.executeUpdate(sql);   
}
            } catch(SQLException e) {  
             System.out.println("Error pada method setInsert()"); 
             return;
            }
```

Comment: Please write down your current output and expected output

Comment: Function `count` always return a value, so, your condition always returns true. Replace to `SELECT * FROM ... `.